# Launch4j not opening even when I have JRE installed

Tags: java, installation, download

I installed the last JDK from [this](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) website (Java SE 14.0.2). This installed both jdk14.0.2 and jre1.8.0_231 in the java folder of my Program Files folder.

I want to make a .exe file out of my jar files using Launch4j however, I can't run Launch4j because everytime I try, it says it requires a java runtime environment. I'm confused because I should already have one installed (jre1.8.0_231), so why isn't it recognizing that?

Comment: There should be a jre tab to fill out.

Comment: Launch4j doesn’t open. That’s the problem. The application itself is not working with my current Java setup.

Comment: Did you setup the environment variables? After downloading jre.

Comment: I never specifically downloaded the jre from Java’s website, I downloaded the SE development kit from oracle’s website which came with jdk and jre. I’ve looked into configuring environment variables, how should I go about doing it?